# Proving a number doesn't divide another and proving $lcm$ using the definition

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

Say I have two integers $a,b$ and I want to prove that $a\not \mid b$ or $ak\neq b$, do I have to take two adjacent $k$s such that $ak_1 < b$ and $ak_2> b$? Is there another way?

Another question, say I want to prove $lcm(9,15)=45$ using $lcm$'s definition, the condition that both divide $45$ is easy, but for proving that there is no $y$ such that $y<45$ and $y$ is divisible by both $9,15$, do I have to show that for every other multiple of $9,15$ that is smaller than $45$ it isn't divisible by $9$ or $15$?

i.e. $9,18,27,36$ aren't divisible by $15$ and $15,30$ aren't divisible by $9$.

Comment: Do you really mean REAL numbers, or is that a typo ?

Comment: @Peter yup a typo.

Comment: It makes no real sense to state in the title "using the definition" and then asking "is there another way?". If you must use the definition, then you must apply whatever definition they gave you. If other methods are allowed, you probably won't be applying the definition (but rather computing $ab/\gcd(a,b)$ instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove that $a$ does not divide $b$, simply calculate $b:a$ with remainder and show
 that the remainder is $\ne 0$.

To prove that $lcm(a,b)=c$ , first show that $a$ and $b$ divide $c$, as you mentioned.

Suppose, $d$ is the $lcm$. Let $c=ed+f$ with $0\le f < d$. Since $c$ and $d$ are common
 multipliers, $f=c-ed$ also is a commom multiplier. If $f$ would be $\ne 0$, $d$ would 
 not be the least common multiplier.

So we can conclude $f=0$. So, $d$ must be a divisor
 of $c$.

So you only have to check the divisors of $c$, if they are common multipliers.

Comment: I'm not asking how to find the $lcm$ I'm asking how to prove it with $lcm$'s definition.

Comment: "Let $c=ad+b$" are these the same parameters from $lcm(a,b)=c$?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I should use other letters here.

Comment: Your final sentence is to be read "you only have to check for the divisors of $c$ _whether_ they are common multiples"? (or in fact, that they are not so). Also note multipliers:=multiples.